# Why the votes to close?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question

I'm mystified by the 3 votes to close that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751973) has received (as of now).

All the votes are under the "not constructive" heading:

> **not constructive**
>
> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

I'm wracking my brain trying to figure out how this question fits the "not constructive" description.

How can I improve it to make it acceptable?

Comment: I guess new users in attempt to gain Badges voted this one. now you need two more votes to see who was the first one to vote to close. If you say I can vote to close...:)

Comment: Really?  Do users get badges for voting to close?  That'd seem like a recipe for chaos...

Comment: yes...Steward(Gold), Reviewer(Silver), Custodian(Bronze)....and many more like Excavator...

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: OK, but what discourages people from voting to close everything in sight, just to rack up badges?

Comment: In your original edit, you asked for a tutorial. That might not have been your entire question, but you were right to remove that request. Questions that ask, mainly, for off-site links are typically closed as not constructive.

Comment: You don't actually have to vote to close to get the review badges, you just have to review posts -- they could vote that the post is fine and still get credit for reviewing it. Excavator doesn't even have anything to do with closing, so I don't know where that came from. Badges for closing lots of questions don't exist, and if they did it wouldn't exactly be hard to find posts that should be closed

Comment: @MichaelMrozek - A more likely motivation is that some people feel the close vote queue needs to be run down to zero, so they vote to close everything within it. Before audits were put into place recently, we had a very large number of users who had voted to close 99-100% of anything they saw in the queue. Unfortunately, "Leave Open" votes don't carry as much weight as close votes, so people see the latter as the fastest way to remove things from the queue.

Comment: Consider clarifying what you mean by "git plumbing". I'm not familiar with the term, "plumbing", and that may help make the question more clear. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [first revision of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16751973/1) asks

> does anyone know of a git tutorial that uses only plumbing commands?

Stack Overflow is not a platform for such requests. As a matter of fact, link-only answers are actively removed. And with a request for tutorials or other resources, it's exactly those answers you invite. Usually that will see such questions closed as "not constructive".

While your question is broader than that, and has now been revised, that to me is a far more likely explanation than users hunting for badges.

Comment: At least 2, maybe 3, of the close-votes arrived *well* after I had deleted that part of the question.

Comment: @kjo I'm unaware of the timing, but that might be. In my experience users who think a question is not the best, tend to follow the votes already given. (Though that is purely gut-feeling, not something I have hard data on). As I originally commented, your current question is still somewhat "do my work for me" in nature, which might explain additional votes. Though I'm just guessing there, given that I am not one of the voters.

Comment: the git documentation is not geared towards the problem of translating "porcelain" to "plumbing", so, AFAIK, there's no "official" RTFM-type work I could do to answer it.

Comment: @kjo which is kinda why I have a hard time coming up with a "and here's how to improve your question".

Comment: thanks...  too bad someone answered the question; i'd delete it otherwise

Comment: @kjo You got some upvotes, the answer got some upvotes, useful content was apparently generated, just leave it be. There is no need to delete anything. Even if it's judged by the community not to be a complete fit for the site.

Answer (score 4):

The question is still too broad after the revision. A full and complete answer would go on for pages and pages of detailed explanation. (Quite aside from the fact that no 'git plumbing' command will be the equivalent of editing something with vim.)

I would recommend splitting this question into several questions. After you do the basic reading on the mapping from garden-variety to plumbing commands, post one or more questions that ask *one* question.

Comment: "A full and complete answer would go on for pages and pages..."  This is, frankly, silly.  The same could be said of any question on SO.  I just posted an answer that is perfectly adequate, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751973 .  It does not "go on for pages and pages", and is typical of the type of answer one finds in SO.